# How to apply multiple or nested cursor and store data in temporary table in my sql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures, cursor, temp-tables

Table 1 : airport

```
Id airportname 
1  NYK(newyork)
2  DXB (dubai)
3  BOM (Bombay) 
4  DEL (delhi)
```

Now My **Rote details**

```
    First Last      Detail Route  
1 : Nyk - BOM : Nyk - DXB - BOM    
2 : Nyk - Del : Nyk - DXB - BOM -Del
```

Table 2 : segmentdetails

```
SegmentdetailsId    RouteId     Originairport     destibation airport  
1                     1          1                   2
2                     1          2                   3 
3                     1          3                   4
4                     2          1                   2
5                     2          2                   3
```

**Note:** user can journy any segment wise on route  e.g. Nyk to DXB (1-2),Nyk - Bom(1 - 3) ,Nyk- Del (1- 4) or Dxb - Bom(2 - 4) etc..

**Now my question is when I pass in parameter as  origin airport ID : 1  and destination ID : 4 so my result would be come as below table in store procedure**

**CASE - 1**
Temptable: routewise_segmentdetails

```
SegmentdetailsId    RouteId    
1                     1  
2                     1  
3                     1
```

**OR**

**Case - 2**
I pass in parameter as  origin airport ID : 1  and destination ID : 3 so my result would be come as below table

Temptable: routewise_segmentdetails

```
SegmentdetailsId    RouteId    
1                     1  
2                     1  

4                     2      
5                     2
```

**OR**

**Case - 3**
I pass in parameter as  origin airport ID : 2  and destination ID : 3 so my result would be come as below table

```
Temptable: routewise_segmentdetails

    SegmentdetailsId    RouteId    
    2                     1  
    5                     2
```

might be I can use nested cursor then I get values but I have not idea about nested cursor  with table.

Comment: which output you want? either 1 or 2?then i will give ans as  per your  requirement.

Comment: @dipali I want to create dynamic query n the basis of origin and destination lets try with 1 , but keep in mind don't compare as number All data as ID

Comment: What is your requirement @Imran? The above output can be easily retrieved by using `OR` between two conditions. But, I think there are more complex in your question. Why you want to create dynamic query and nested cursor?

Comment: @winky yes agreed above out put can retrieve by or query in case-2 and case - 3 only ,but what about case-1 

 let see my route is 1-2-3-4(airport id)
now I can journey 1- 4 or 2- 3 or 1-3 .and my other fare and timing details is based on segmentdetailsID

Comment: Now your question is cleared... OK, I am trying

Comment: Are you looking for retrieve record between given AirportID and DestinationID? Because, Your third case output is looking different then others.

Comment: @winky Let see, you entered 2 entered  as origin and destination is 3 now match with route , 1>Nyk - DXB - BOM  2> Nyk - DXB - BOM - del now you applicable in both rote and you got 2 and 5 as segmentdetails is

Comment: @Imran solved or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as the structure of your table - and the way you store data means that segmentDetails are stored sequentially. Given that bit of info, you don't need to store any stuffs in temp tables or anything like that at all.

I think that this should do the trick - you just write two subqueries, each pulling a distinct routeId and joining it back to the original table as well as each other, but also constrain the outer query by the same params you use in the subqueries:

```
select
    core.segmentDetailsId,
    core.routeId
from
    segmentDetails core
        join (
            select distinct
                routeId
            from
                segmentDetails
            where
                originAirport=param1    
        ) sub1
        on core.routeId=sub1.routeId
        join (
            select distinct
                routeId
            from
                segmentDetails
            where
                destinationAirport=param2       
        ) sub2
        on core.routeId=sub2.routeId
        and sub1.routeId=sub2.routeId
where
    core.originAirport>=param1
    and core.destinationAirport<=param2
order by
    segmentDetailsId,
    routeId
```

Edit: I haven't actually tested this, but I think it is likely to work. If not, leave me a comment and I will have another look.

Edit 2: I think your case 2 is wrong based on what you seem to be asking:

**Case ------- 2**
I pass in parameter as  origin airport ID : 1  and destination ID : 3 so my result would be come as below table

Temptable: routewise_segmentdetails

```
SegmentdetailsId    RouteId    
1                     1  
2                     1  
3??                   1??
4                     2      
5                     2
```

You put destination as 3, yet you are showing SegDetId 3, which has an ORIGIN of 3, yet a destination of 4. I take it you meant to NOT show this row in your results?

Comment: Excellent and fantastic. Nice solution ,And for your query segmentdetails Id 3 and routeid 1 is not coming

Answer (score 1):

Here is final sql which consider all posibilities

```
select SegmentdetailsId   , RouteId
from segmentdetails
where ORIGINAIRPORT >= 2 and DESTIBATIONAIRPORT<= 3
```

Answer (score -1):

This will return your intended result set...You can try with creating two provided tables and run the following SQL which will definately return your intended result set:

```
select SegmentdetailsId,RouteId from segmentdetails
    where destinationairport<= "Your Number'
```

Comment: This will return only destination airport route , but actually I want all segment details with origin and destination also . pair is 1-2,2-3,3-4 so segment detail id is 1,2,3,with route 1

Comment: thx but If my originid = 1 and destinationid = 4 then it would be work ?
as  I tested records only comes for  only
     <hr/> 
segmentid          routeid       origin      destination 
<hr/>
1                     1          1                   2
2                     1          2                   3 
3                     1          3                   4      
<hr/>    
segments : 1 - 2 , 3 - 4 but still 2-3 (segment remain )record missing